# Pre-compile TypeScript Vue components with template string

Tags: typescript, webpack, vue.js, vue-component

I have a Vue site that is built with Webpack. I have a TypeScript file that contains a component:

```
// my-component.ts

import Vue = require('vue');
    
export default Vue.component("my-component", {
    template: "<div>I am a component</div>"
});
```

When I try to use this component I get the following warning:

> You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template option is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.

Now: how do I pre-compile this template? I know I can [define a `.vue` file](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) and even use TypeScript inside `<script></script>`, but I would rather define my component in pure TypeScript so that I get nice TypeScript support in WebStorm.

Is this possible?

---

(I know I can also go with the second option by creating an alias for the compiler-included build at `vue/dist/vue.js` but I feel like this gives me a performance penalty. At the very least, it adds 20kb to my build.)

---

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use the `standalone build` to do this, simply add the following to your webpack config (this is for the most recent `Vue` release):

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js'
  }
}
```

And it should pull in the standalone build for you, which includes the template option.

---

If you want to have a go at creating your own `render functions` then you can. At it's most basic you would get:

```
Vue.component('msg', {
  functional: true,
  render: (createElement, context) => {
    return createElement('div', context.props.message)
  },
  props: ['message']
})
```

It's a little more complex, but actually not too bad if you really don't like the idea of using `.vue` files and your templates are relatively straightforward, here's the fiddle for the above component:

https://jsfiddle.net/et67zqdp/

It's then worth taking a look at:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html

Comment: Hey thanks, I should've added to my question that I considered this. But it probably hurts performance? In addition to adding 30kb to the final bundle size...

Comment: Yes, there is a bit of a trade off, `Vue` compiles the template at run-time in the `standalone build` so you have to accept that performance hit (in most cases it's probably negligible). However, if performance is more of an issue then you should consider using `.vue` files and compiling them instead. Internally `vue` compiles `.vue` files into render functions suitable for use with the `runtime-only` build.

Comment: EDIT: it does not seem possible to define the script part of a component in its own .js file, and then the only the template in a `.vue` file? Because that would be perfect for my situation. https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/start/spec.html: 'A *.vue file is a custom file format that uses HTML-like syntax to describe a Vue component. Each *.vue file consists of three types of top-level language blocks: <template>, <script> and <style>'

Comment: You were correct all along, I can just use a relative file "If you prefer splitting up your *.vue components into multiple files, you can use the src attribute to import an external file for a language block:": `<script src="./script.js"></script>`

Comment: @craig_h yea indeed a trade off. This caused performance issues in our project. Does anyone know if it is possible to pre-compile the templates in Typescript without having to convert everything to .vue files?

Comment: The documentation at https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/deployment.html#Pre-Compiling-Templates suggests to use https://github.com/ktsn/vue-template-loader if you want to keep the templates separate. I did not give it a try yet, but look like an option to check.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is the go to way or not:
But I just create a file in the root of the project (same place where your "package.json" is located) named

"vue.config.js"

```
module.exports = {
  runtimeCompiler: true
}
```

Comment: I think it's more "The way to go".

Comment: But is it the way to go?
Or did you just want to correct my grammar? o.O :D

Comment: Mostly just the grammar mistake. Hahah